# How can I break a table row into two table rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a wide table that I would like to split each row into two rows, after each cell with the class "column-6".

```
$( ".column-6" ).after( "</tr><tr class='secondary'>" );
```

For some reason it is included as:

```
<tr class="secondary"></tr>
```

JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/xa9nk/1/

Comment: I didn't get it, so if each row is devidede into two rows, then how about the table header??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the `html` of the `table`. First you have to insert the token at the positions you want, then perform the replacement of the token with the string you want (which is `</tr><tr class='secondary'>`):

```
var yourOtherFace = jQuery.noConflict();
var token = "sdfdskjflsfj34234ksldjfskdl";

yourOtherFace( ".column-6" ).after(token)
 .closest('table').html(function(i,oldHtml){
     return oldHtml.replace(new RegExp(token,"g"), "</tr><tr class='secondary'>");     
 });

yourOtherFace('.column-1').attr('rowspan', '2');
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/xa9nk/3/)

Here's another solution using pure Regex without inserting some `token` first, it may be shorter but I've made a test case and looks like it's about 40% slower than the first solution (using `token`).

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/xa9nk/4/)

Here is the [performance test](http://jsperf.com/relace-with-token-vs-replace-with-regex).

Comment: 1+, It works, but is it user friendly???it is confusing to divide table row this way, isn't it?? At least the column header should be prefixed to each td if I care about user interface readability

Comment: @stackunderflow I have to admit that it's not really user friendly, but I think it can be used in some case (with tooltip supported when hovering the cell). Anyway that's what the OP wants, I don't really care about why he wants so.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Solid solution.

I hadn't really gone through how user friendly it would be, just trying to sort out the best way to display this much data.